# Angular 2 routerLink dynamic vs static

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm developing an Angular2 App and have this problem:

I have 2 links defined like this:

```
<a *ngFor="..." class="collapsible" [routerLink]="['/admin', 'categories',kind.id,'products']">
                    {{kind.name}}
</a>
<a class="collapsible" routerLink="/admin/other">Other Link</a>
```

Both links actually work but there's one problem. The second one, seems to only update the contents in `router-outlet` . That's ok because it updates pretty fast. BUT the first one reloads the entire page, reloading all angular 2 again.

Is this an error from myself or an error in angular 2? Or not at error at all but a misunderstanding of how `routerLink` works.

Thanks

Comment: it seems there is an issue with the link that is being hit because i use the dynamic router link and it doesnt reload the whole page.

Comment: Which angular 2 version are you using? I'm using rc6